# python docx, como agregar saltos de linea en un parrafo y establecer un color diferente a un texto

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-docx

Al utilizar la libreria `docx` para generar archivos `word` me encuntro con 2 problemas:

1.- Al agregar un nuevo texto al parrafo no respesta el salto de linea `\n`

2.- No puedo cambiar el color al texto especifico

El resultado que espero obtener seria algo asi:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pero el resultado final es:

**Nombre:MiNombre**

Este es mi codigo:

```
import docx
from docx.shared import Inches,Cm,RGBColor
from docx.enum.text import WD_PARAGRAPH_ALIGNMENT


documento = docx.Document()
for seccion in documento.sections:
    seccion.left_margin = Cm(2)
    seccion.right_margin = Cm(2)
seccion = documento.sections[0]

seccion_titulo = seccion.header

encabezado = seccion_titulo.add_paragraph()
encabezado_run = encabezado.add_run()
encabezado_run.add_text("\t\t\t\t\t\tRegistro de alumno")
encabezado_run.add_text("\n__________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________")

t = "Nombre:"
t1 = "\nMiNombre"
tabla = documento.add_table(rows=1,cols=2)
celda = tabla.rows[0].cells

tabla_celda = celda[0].add_paragraph().add_run()
p= tabla_celda.add_text(t)
p1 = tabla_celda.add_text(t1)
font = p1.font
font.color.rgb = RGBColor(125,125,125)

documento.save("Nuevo.docx")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Revsky01, de acuerdo a la documentación de `python-docx`, se debe agregar un objeto `Run` al párrafo, y sobre éste agregar un **salto**, el cual puede ser:

- WD_BREAK.LINE
- WD_BREAK.PAGE
- WD_BREAK.COLUMN

El salto de línea, `WD_BREAK.LINE`, es el valor por defecto.

```
import docx

documento = docx.Document()
parrafo = documento.add_paragraph("Primera línea")
parrafo.add_run().add_break()
parrafo.add_run("Segunda línea")
documento.save("Dos líneas.docx")
```